# Using x509 PKI with PGP

Tags: key-authentication, certificates, pgp

I'm building x509 PKI. And I want to apply CA's concept to my own private apt-get repository. I just found that apt-get repository (reprepro) use PGP certificate and some textbook said they can't use mix of them. But I just see another textbook said it could. I want to know if it is possible to integrate both of them in same structure.